# Best way to clean up this book page for OCR

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

https://pasteboard.co/J5FM06V.png

What would be the best way to clean up this image for OCR using opencv with python?

I'm really not good at this part. Could someone give me a hand, please?

Comment: This is too broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: I'm just wondering what would be the best opencv filters and how to apply them, using opencv with python, so ocr would work better. It's not vague... It's just not much to ask.

Comment: Use adaptiveThreshold()

Comment: @ankh _It's not vague..._ It may be too vague for Stack Overflow, was my point.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905592/automatic-contrast-and-brightness-adjustment-of-a-color-photo-of-a-sheet-of-pape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try would be some thresholding techniques. There is a [great tutorial here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

You might want to look at some [morphology operations](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).